Cannot find module 'express', error when installing express
I have successfully deployed my Node.js project on a Ubuntu VPS, but when I try to run it, it's showing an error Error: Cannot find module 'express' - as shown in (1), even though I have installed Express, it gives another error as shown (2). After installing Express, when I try to run node app.js, it gives another error as shown in (3).

When I start running 'node app.js', it gives the error below not found 'express'.
root@GreenCloud:/home/test-tnp# node app.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1093
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'express'
Require stack:
- /home/test-tnp/app.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1090:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:934:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:119:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/test-tnp/app.js:1:17)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1133:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/home/test-tnp/app.js' ]
}


After that, I tried to install the 'express' library and noticed there were errors related to some dependencies, as shown below.
root@GreenCloud:/home/test-tnp# npm install express
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'dns@0.2.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>= 0.10.0 < 0.11.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v19.9.0', npm: '9.6.3' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'hawk@0.10.2',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '0.8.x' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v19.9.0', npm: '9.6.3' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'hoek@0.7.6',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '0.8.x' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v19.9.0', npm: '9.6.3' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'tomahawk@0.1.6',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>= 0.8.0 < 0.11.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v19.9.0', npm: '9.6.3' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN deprecated sane@4.1.0: some dependency vulnerabilities fixed, support for node < 10 dropped, and newer ECMAScript syntax/features added
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN tarball tarball data for emitter@http://github.com/component/emitter/archive/1.0.1.tar.gz (sha512-k3Da+QreMb9waaGCHNAHox5QqxnZEYlQmvIVYwQibrI6OpIRyIIyFGgDV5dXRLr1AJ32JLqEh0VxQEq20dFskw==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm WARN deprecated jssha@2.3.1: jsSHA versions < 3.0.0 will no longer receive feature updates
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! sha512-k3Da+QreMb9waaGCHNAHox5QqxnZEYlQmvIVYwQibrI6OpIRyIIyFGgDV5dXRLr1AJ32JLqEh0VxQEq20dFskw== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-k3Da+QreMb9waaGCHNAHox5QqxnZEYlQmvIVYwQibrI6OpIRyIIyFGgDV5dXRLr1AJ32JLqEh0VxQEq20dFskw== but got sha512-r/UcFj7JS3lRjv9cgYjgpDNbAsGUdqU64n6ZUOgSF7s1UFBbGu7pUDwKEjHu9NBCy6j2AmmjNW4rijR4De65eA==. (2809 bytes)


When I tried to run again after installing Express, the app reported another error, not finding the 'index.js' file.
root@GreenCloud:/home/test-tnp# node app.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:456
      throw err;
      ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/test-tnp/node_modules/debug/src/index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
    at tryPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:448:19)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:692:18)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1076:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:934:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:119:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/test-tnp/node_modules/finalhandler/index.js:14:13)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1133:32) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: '/home/test-tnp/node_modules/debug/package.json',
  requestPath: 'debug'
}



My package.json file:
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app.js",
    "dev": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "bson": "^5.3.0",
    "company-email-validator": "^1.0.9",
    "country-code-lookup": "^0.0.22",
    "cryptocurrency-address-detector": "^1.1.2",
    "dnsbl": "^3.2.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "email-provider": "^1.0.1",
    "email-syntax-check": "^1.1.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-validator": "^6.15.0",
    "ip-to-hosting": "^1.0.6",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "legit": "^1.0.9",
    "libphonenumber-geo-carrier": "^1.2.6",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.10.24",
    "mail-listener5": "^2.1.2",
    "mongoose": "^6.8.3",
    "mongoose-unique-validator": "^3.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "trezor-address-validator": "^0.4.3",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0"
  }
}

When i run 'npm ls express', it shows new error below
root@GreenCloud:/home/test-tnp# npm ls express
npm ERR! code ELSPROBLEMS
npm ERR! invalid: express@ /home/test-tnp/node_modules/express
npm ERR! invalid: express@ /home/test-tnp/node_modules/tomahawk/node_modules/express
npm ERR! extraneous: express@ /home/test-tnp/node_modules/tomahawk/node_modules/express
backend@1.0.0 /home/test-tnp
├── express@ invalid: "^4.19.2" from the root project
└─┬ tomahawk@0.1.6 extraneous
  └── express@ invalid: "4.6.1" from node_modules/tomahawk extraneous


Please give a [mre] with appropriate formatting.

It looks like your package.json may have some very old dependencies, so old in fact that they're from the year 2013 (over 10 years old) and not supported by the current Node.js version you're using.

@jonrsharpe What additional information do you need? I don't quite understand your point. Basically, when I run the command 'node app.js', I get errors in the order like in block (1), (2), (3) :(

@cbr A few days ago, I was able to connect to the API normally. However, after I reinstalled Ubuntu and redeployed the project, I started getting errors like the ones mentioned above :(

Edit your question to include your package.json

You need to give enough information that when someone else runs node app.js they get the same errors. But as above it seems like your dependencies are completely wrecked.

I have updated the 'package.json' file, please check it for me. Thank you very much

Still neither minimal nor reproducible.

@jonrsharpe Would you like more information about the full source code? I'm still not clear on what additional information you're asking me to provide :(

I found that problem maybe come from pakage: tomahawk, I have updated new source code above

When I updated Node.js to version 20.x and npm to 10.x, it resolved the issue. Running it no longer encounters errors. Thank you all for paying attention to this topic!

When I updated Node.js to version 20.x (the previsous version was 16.x) and npm to 10.x, it resolved the issue. Running it no longer encounters errors. Thank you all for paying attention to this topic!
